# Trouble Resetting the position of a div after dragging using JQuery callbacks

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate, draggable

I'm trying to create a draggable div (constrained to the x axis) using JQuery that will reset to it's original position when dragged. This is what I have so far but the animate function won't work, I've tried replacing ui.draggable with ui.animate with no luck.

Here's what I have written, I'd appreciate whatever help you can give!

```
$( '.selectedResult' ).draggable({
start: function(event, ui){
    startPosition = ui.position.left;
},
stop: function(event, ui){
    var move = startPosition - ui.position.left;

    if(move > 0){
        move = '+=' + move;
    }else{
        move = -move;
        move = '-=' + move;
    }

    $(ui.draggable).animate({'left': move}, 'slow');
},
axis: 'x'                                       
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is ok except `$(ui.draggable).animate({'left': move}, 'slow');`. Replace it with

```
$(ui.helper).animate({'left': move}, 'slow');
```